# How many decimal places should a volume measurement in a beaker include?

Tags: experimental-chemistry, equipment

I have a beaker which goes up in $0.5~\mathrm{mL}$ increments and my teacher told me that my measurement $(15.50~\mathrm{mL})$ was incorrect, and instead the answer was $15.5~\mathrm{mL}$. I don't understand. I know that the liquid is between $15.5~\mathrm{mL}$ and $16~\mathrm{mL}$. My estimated digit is $0$ (it looks like it lies on the line), so my answer is $15.50~\mathrm{mL}$. How is it $15.5~\mathrm{mL}$?

Comment: When you say $15.50$, it assumes that you have the measurement correct up to 2 decimals. Since you're measuring equipment can do only one decimal, you should report it likewise. So, though numerically $15.50 = 15.5$, they mean different in terms of accuracy of reporting.

Comment: Technically your teacher is correct. Since your beaker only has increments of 0.5 mL, you can only _report_ a volume measurement to the nearest 0.5 mL. However, what you did is also a common practice and appropriate in some cases. Your eyeball can certainly interpolate to within a couple tenths or so by estimating the level of the liquid as you described. You can do this as one element of a calculation for example, but in the end you have to round your _final result_ to the level of accuracy that your beaker measures to, since you don't actually know what the uncertainty of your eyeball is ;)

Comment: @airhuff - That just isn't true. If you have a burette marked to tenths of a ml  then as you pointed out you can interpolate to 0.01 ml. The error isn't +/- 0.01 but probably something more like +/- 0.02. But that is a lot better precision and accuracy than rounding off to 0.1 ml. // That being said, teachers make the rules in their classes.

Comment: Now that I've thought about it -- are you sure that your glassware is a beaker? I don't think I've ever seen a beaker graduated that finely. Can you link to a picture of something similar?

Comment: If it's actually not a beaker but a graduated cylinder or other volumetric instrument, see also: [Using sigfigs when measuring with an instrument with marks other than powers of ten?](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/37649/7951)

Comment: @hBy2Py If that thing really has graduation divisions of 0.5 ml, it's probably a 25 ml graduated cylinder and not a beaker.

Comment: @Loong Exactly my suspicion. The 'beak' of a grad cylinder does look a lot like that of a beaker.

Answer (score 7):

**It may have to do with the fact that it's a beaker, rather than some other kind of glassware.**

First, beakers are poor vessels for volumetric measurements due to their large diameter/height ratios.  You have to add a lot of liquid, relatively speaking, in order to increase the height of the fill level by (say) a millimeter, and that means the uncertainty in the fill volume is large.

As well, [beakers are usually not graduated precisely](https://www.dartmouth.edu/~chemlab/techniques/flasks.html). Thus, even if you *very very carefully* fill the beaker to *exactly* the $15.5~\mathrm{mL}$ line with liquid, ***there's a very real chance that the line doesn't actually correspond exactly to a $\mathit{15.5~mL}$ fill volume.***

So, unlike with a piece of glassware specifically made for accurate volumetric measurements, such as the burette mentioned by MaxW in a comment, it is likely not appropriate to assign more significant figures to a beaker measurement than are "available" in the graduation increment.