# Measuring Cylinders -- small or big?

Tags: experimental-chemistry

My teacher often recommends the usage of a smaller/more narrow measuring cylinder over a larger one while performing experiments but why is that? Does it help in accuracy in any way?

Comment: The relative cylinder resolution is given by the height resolution divided by the actual  height difference. Which of the narrower versus wider cylinder gives better value of this parameter for a given volume?

Comment: Related answer: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/37788/101286

Comment: Adding an excess of ten drops in a narrow cylinder is visible : it does make a difference. It does not in a wide cylinder. The accuracy is better in a narrow cylinder.

Comment: That is why a volumetric container always has a narrow neck.

Comment: Well, that explains why my 1 cm long thermometer, with 10 cm diameter, is so insensitive and hard to read! ;-)